# Retrieving token from Email Angular 6

Tags: angular, email, token

When a user register an email is sent to them from the API with a token to verify the user. an endpoint of the API requires the token to verify the user, how do I get the token and post it to the API

Comment: Put a link to an open endpoint inside the email (the link contains a query or path param with the token)

Comment: well the link in the email is something like this http://www.hello.com/verify?token=[value]

Answer (score 5):

Include a clickable url in your registrationmail which includes the token as query parameter. e.g. `https://website.com/confirmRegistration?token=insertTokenHere`

then create a component and a route for /confirmRegistration, inject `ActivatedRoute` into that component and read the token with `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('token');`. use the Value to call the API endpoint.

Comment: snapshot might not give the updated value of the `token` in all the cases. Subscribing to `queryParams` is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a URL like this in your Email:

`https://www.hello.com/verify?token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE`

Let's break it down into steps:

1. You might have routing implemented that will load a Component for a Specific Route. So you might have something like this:

   `{ path: 'verify', component: VerifyComponent }`
2. Now in the `VerifyComponent`  TypeScript Class, you can inject `ActivatedRoute` as a Dependency.

   `import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
   ...
   constructor(..., private route: ActivatedRoute) {}`
3. Now in the the `ngOnInit` of this Component, you can have access to the token like this:

   `ngOnInit() {
     this.route.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
       const token = queryParams['token'];
       // Call your Backend API with the token after this
     });
   }`

Comment: thank you, Ill look into params more but this really helped a lot

Comment: @D1ZZYD23, are you passing the token as a `param` or as a `queryParam` ?

Comment: queryParam, whats the difference?

Comment: queryParams come after `?` in a URL and are separated by `&`. And params come as a part of the `url` following a `/`. You'll have to specify a `/:paramName` in Angular Routing when using params but not in case of using `queryParams`. Also, you `subscribe` to `params` on the `ActivatedRoute` to get the `params` but to get `queryParams` you `subscribe` to `queryParams`.

Comment: @D1ZZYD23, were you able to achieve what you were trying to, following this answer?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Why use a subscription? You could get the params directly.

Comment: @lonix, did you get a chance to read my comment on the answer above?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Ok I see your comment about snapshot. But why will snapshot not give real value? That isn't documented anywhere.